# not able to exit from loop

Tags: shell, loops

i have a created a code to parse hostname,username and privilege from files in a dir..how ever i am not able to exit at the end of the code .the loop gives perfact data output.but not giving shell prompt back.
array arg[] contain name of file value

```
c=0

while((c<=${#arg[*]}))

 do

hname=`grep -e "^hostname" ${arg[$c]} |awk '{ print $2 }'| sort |uniq`

if [[ -n $hname ]]

then
     logDebug "data found for the $hname"

while read -r line; do

for term in "echo $line"; do

    if [[ "$term" =~ (username)[[:space:]](.*?) ]]; then

         userid=`echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" | awk '{print $1}'`

            logDebug "username: $userid"


            if [[ "$term" =~ (privilege)[[:space:]](.*?) ]]; then

             Priv=`echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" | awk '{print $1}'`

             PRIV=`echo "level=$Priv"`

             logDebug "Privilege: $PRIV"

                echo"$CUSTOMER|S|$hname|$OS|$userid|$Uid_Conv|$Uic_mode|$State|$i_login|$group|$PRIV|" >> "$OutputFile"

            fi

    fi
   done
done < "${arg[$c]}"

fi


let c=c+1
done
```

Comment: Would this link be of any help?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/while-read-line-in-shell-script-how-to-stop-the-loop?rq=1

Comment: `for term in "echo $line"` doesn't do anything useful (it prepends the word `echo` to your line, then runs the `for` loop exactly once, with the prefixed string in `term`). Maybe you want to replace `read -r line` with `read -r -a terms`, then `for term in "${terms[@]}"; do`?

Comment: ...btw, I'd suggest running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds -- there are some quoting issues; nothing responsible for your immediate bug, but it's worth reducing the amount of uncertainty about what happens at runtime by dotting i's and crossing t's.

Comment: HI ,thanx for all the suggestion.stil the issue exists.the program is not taking any exit.and i think its in line
hname=`grep -e "^hostname" ${arg[$c]} |awk '{ print $2 }'| sort |uniq`
after it read the last data value from the file.it stops and dont exit.

Answer (score 0):

For your first while clause...I would use

```
for ((c=0;c<${#arg[*];c++)); do
     .....
done
```

Getting rid of the c=0 and let c=c+1

Comment: Why use a numeric `c` at all? `for item in "${arg[@]}"; do` iterates directly over the objects and avoids any need to index into them (so you can refer to `"$item"`, not `"${arg[$c]}"`. Moreover, it's compatible with all POSIX-compliant shells rather than requiring bash extensions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Since it's filename with possibly full path, aren't you afraid that the resulting string of "${arg[@]} might be too long ? That said, I agree, it's more elegant.

Comment: What do you mean by "too long"? A variable that isn't exported (and thus using limited environment space) just goes on the heap, like any other (non-stack/register) variable in any other language; there are only relatively low limits (on the scale of hundreds of KB on modern systems) for cumulative storage of environment variables and command-line arguments. The OP's code is passing `"${arg[$c]}"` on the command line to `grep`, so the pertinent limit applies at that time regardless.